# Regarding the pipeline, how to wait for function to finish before carrying on?

Tags: powershell

I am working on a module and am struggling with getting one of its functions to work synchronously with other commandlets in the pipeline.
Here is a simpe version of the function:

```
function Invoke-ShareX {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Position = 0)]
        [ArgumentCompletions('ActiveMonitor', 'ActiveWindow')]
        [String]$Action,
        [String]$Destination
    )
    Process{
        switch ($PSBoundParameters.keys) {
            "Action" {
                switch ($Action) {
                    'ActiveMonitor'{ShareX -Workflow ActiveMonitor;(WatchClipboard) | get-item -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue}
                    'ActiveWindow' {}
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The above function is rellying on another function that is internal to the module:

```
function WatchClipboard {Set-clipboard $null; While ((Get-Clipboard).Length -eq 0){Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 10; Get-Clipboard}}
```

I am essentially using ShareX to:

- Trigger a preconfigured action via its Command Line

  - Take a screenshot
  - Place the path of the image file on my clipboard
- Return this path to the host/pipeline for other commandlets

The problem I am having is, the next commandlet on the pipeline misses the returned object, for example:

```
Invoke-ShareX -Action ActiveMonitor
```

Will return

```
C:\Users\...\Documents\ShareX\Screenshots\Monitor__1120.jpg
```

But doing something like

```
Invoke-ShareX -Action ActiveMonitor | move -Destination $Temp
```

Will return an error:

```
Move-Item: Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.
```

How can I pause flow of execution until up to the point the path is returned to the host\pipe?

Comment: your `WatchClipboard` has a bug in it, `Get-Clipboard` should be outside the `while` loop not inside. most likely explains your error

Comment: Good catch, fixed now! this lead me to the right direction. Thanks mate